# WebAssembly LinkError: function import requires a callable

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I've recently started working with WebAssembly. I hit a problem trying to use log in my C code. I recreated the error in the simplest way I could. The error I get is

```
Uncaught (in promise) LinkError: WebAssembly.Instance(): Import #1 module="env" function="_log" error: function import requires a callable
```

The error points to this function, specifically `WebAsembly.Instance(module, imports)`

```
function loadWebAssembly(filename, imports = {}) {
  return fetch(filename)
    .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then((buffer) => WebAssembly.compile(buffer))
    .then((module) => {
      imports.env = imports.env || {}
      Object.assign(imports.env, {
        memoryBase: 0,
        tableBase: 0,
        memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
          initial: 256,
          maximum: 512,
        }),
        table: new WebAssembly.Table({
          initial: 0,
          maximum: 0,
          element: 'anyfunc',
        }),
      })
      return new WebAssembly.Instance(module, imports)
    })
}
```

(I call this function with `loadWebAssembly('/test.wasm')`)

My C code is

```
#include <math.h>

double test(v) {
  return log(v)
}
```

and gets no errors when compiled with

```
emcc test.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o test.wasm
```

I haven't been able to fix this error, I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't providing an implementation of `log()` in `imports.env`

```
Object.assign(imports.env, {
    memoryBase: 0,
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 256,
        maximum: 512,
    }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({
        initial: 0,
        maximum: 0,
        element: 'anyfunc',
    }),
    _log: Math.log,
})
```

Comment: But that way the wasm code will just run the JS function instead of the C implementation...right?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz have you found out the answer for this? Will it just run the js version or somehow will utilize the C version of log? Thanks!

Comment: @NikitaPestrov the log above runs the JS Math.log version, I haven't found another solution.

Comment: this didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

*I might be wrong but I think your C code is wrong*

By default emscripten exports only `main` function others are as dead code

you need to tell the `emscripten` to keep alive the `test` function by using macro `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE`

and don't forget to include header file `emscripten/emscripten.h`

For more info go to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm#calling_a_custom_function_defined_in_c)

## test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <math.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
double test(double x)
{
    return log(x);
}
```

and you can access your function in js

## JavaScript

```js
loadWebAssembly('test.wasm')
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.exports) // {__wasm_call_ctors: ƒ, log10: ƒ}
    }).
    catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```